# Collect text from google slides

Tags: r

Has one tried to collect all the text from google slides inside one folder to one large chunk of text using R? We are trying the understand the language and the messages being used in all our presentations over the last few years. Once we collect all the text we would like to try and use this to generate insights going forward.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this is to probably download all power points as pptx, and loop over every file to read in every pptx.

You can use the "officer" package to read over all the power points and save the text as you go.

Example:

```
library(officer)

ppt_files = list.files(...\\ppt, pattern = ".ppt$", full.names = TRUE)


for (i in ppt_files){
ppt = pptx_summary(read_pptx(i))

### more code here

}
```